# Code Analysis and SupressMessage - Should you wrap the attribute with #if DEBUG

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, code-analysis, roslyn

I'm looking at using SupressMessage to eat some CA warnings.  The doc for SupressMessage says to make sure its not in the release builds.  Accordingly, should the SupressMessage attribute be wrapped in #if DEBUG as follows?

```
public class Class1
{
#if DEBUG
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA1801:ReviewUnusedParameters", MessageId = "args")]
#endif
    static void Main(string[] args) { }

#if DEBUG
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage",
    "CA1806:DoNotIgnoreMethodResults", MessageId = "System.Guid")]
#endif
    public static bool IsValidGuid(string guid)
    {
        try
        {
            new Guid(guid); //Causes CA1806: DoNotIgnoreMethodResults
            return true;
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException) { }
        catch (OverflowException) { }
        catch (FormatException) { }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Reference: For more information see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244717.aspx

> You should not use in-source suppressions on release builds to prevent shipping the in-source suppression metadata accidentally. Because of the processing cost of in-source suppression, the performance of your application can also be degraded by including the in-source suppression metadata.

Comment: The documentation also states that the attribute class is attributed with `[ConditionalAttribute("CODE_ANALYSIS")]`, never bothered with looking into this but perhaps it isn't in release builds anyway?

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not. Just make sure your release build does not define the conditional compilation symbol `CODE_ANALYSIS`.

The reason is that `SuppressMessageAttribute` has a `[ConditionalAttribute("CODE_ANALYSIS")]`, which means it won't be included in the output DLL, unless `CODE_ANALYSIS` is defined.

As [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) says:

> Applying ConditionalAttribute to an attribute indicates that the attribute should not be emitted to metadata unless the conditional compilation symbol is defined.

Be aware that turning on "Enable Code Analysis on Build" may add the conditional compilation symbol `CODE_ANALYSIS` to your Build settings, so make sure that is not the case on your release build.